# Where can I ask about the support status of Node.js for UNIX?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is the following question on-topic for the main site?  If not, is it on-topic on another SE site?

> I know the Node.js is available via **freeBSD** `pkg` or probably with `ports`. I have actually had an installation from the `pkg` recently.
>   However, on Nodejs.org ther is no version for any UNIX or freeBSD. Does that mean it is not officially supported by Node.js?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Node.js. Unless Joyent has employees authorized to make that call watching SO, it's unlikely any of the volunteers on SO can give you an official statement. Thanks for asking before posting though.